# Deploying Azure Stream Analytics error (The number of template input parameters limit exceeded. Limit: '256') using DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I have generated the ARM templates for my Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) solution using

`<package id="Microsoft.Azure.StreamAnalytics.CICD" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />`

However, since I have multiple inputs and outputs in my ASA, when generated the ARM template, it contains 282 parameters. which is exceeding the limit of 256, and I getting error while deploying it using Azure DevOps pipeline.

I know, we can create nested/linked ARM templates to resolved the issue.
But if I start creating them using the actual ARM generated manually, it will take lot of time.

Is there any way we can have a automated way of creating the nested templates, for ASA to avoid this issue ? Need help on the same.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you get to 282 parameters for a single job? How many inputs and outputs do you have? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into switching from ARM deployments to using a CLI like [az cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/stream-analytics?view=azure-cli-latest) or [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.streamanalytics/?view=azps-7.3.0)?

Comment: @FlorianEiden We have around 3 inputs and around 30 outputs. So when we use the package which I have mentioned to build the Stream Analytics solution it's creates the ARM template which has like minimum 5/6 parameters for each of our input and output plus it's own parameters. No I didn't explored using Az cli / powershell to deploy ASA to azure.

Comment: Sadly I won't be able to help here. Now 30 outputs is a lot more that is usually recommended - but I understand how that can make sense in certain use cases (happy to see if that could be reduced if you're interested in that). There is no going around the ARM limit, so either you switch to CLI/PS, or you continue down the path of nested/linked templates (of which I know nothing about sadly). Sorry about that!